# Why some special/control chars in a makefile on *nix at times give errors during make?

Tags: makefile

I have experienced at times that if any special/control character($,^M, or something else) somehow gets into a makefile, then if u try to make -f Makefile  using that makefile it gives errors.

I want to know,

1.) Has anyone experienced something like this, and if yes, what causes these errors? What is peculiar about these special chars?

Comment: I don't see what a satisfactory answer would be, and therefore I don't think this is a real question.  Extremely vague, and the answer is something like "because that's what make does".

Comment: @goldenmean: Local custom calls for leaving off the salutation to save space on the front-page, and your authorship is automatically displayed, so the sign-off is also unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

UNIX traditionally is not very forgiving with input to programs. That attitude hasn't changed much since its first inception. `^M` is carriage return which usually only gets into files when editing them in Windows environments. UNIX uses the line feed (\n, 0x0a) as line terminator and many tools complain about CR (\r, 0x0d) as they don't see a reason why that character should even exist.

`$` are a different issue, as `$` is part of makefile syntax. It's used to indicate variables/constants in makefiles. Those can be contextual ones, like `$<` or `$*`, or named ones like `$(CC)`.

You can use the `dos2unix` utility to get rid of `^M` and escape dollar signs with `\$`.

There are more peculiarities to make, nonetheless. For example the requirement that command lines for targets need to be indented by a tab character. As far as I know only `make`s not very widely used have lifted that restriction.

Comment: @Johannes Rossel: Would these peculiar requirements for a makefile text formatting be explanined in the man Make or info make or some other make help.

Comment: Those should usually be documented, yes. But most people writing makefiles know about them anyway :)